# Loop missing iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to test if the word I am iterating through is capital. If the word is not capital and not in the dictionary it should be printed as is. If the word is not capital and not in the dictionary it should be replaced and printed. If the word is capital it needs to be made lowercase to test if it is in the dictionary. If it is capital and in the dictionary the word should be replaced and printed. If it is capital and not in the dictionary the word should be made capital again and printed.

I have tried both of the codes below and they appear to be doing the same thing. It is not changing the capital letters. It is possibly not even iterating over them.

```py
def replace_mode(text_list,misspelling):
    update = ''
#loop iterates over the lines and over each word
    for line in text_list:
        word = line.split(' ')
        for key in word:
            if key.isupper():
                key = key.lower()
                if key in misspelling.keys(): #checks if the word is in the dictionary
                    update = misspelling[key]
                    print(update.capitalize(), end=(' '))
                else: 
                    print(key.capitalize(), end=(' '))
            elif key in misspelling.keys():
                update = misspelling[key]
                print(update, end=(' '))
            else:  
                print(key, end=(' '))
        print()
```

```
def replace_mode(text_list,misspelling):
    update = ''
#loop iterates over the lines and over each word
    for line in text_list:
        word = line.split(' ')
        for key in word:
            capital = False
            if key.isupper():
                capital = True
                key = key.lower()
            if capital == True:
                if key in misspelling.keys(): #checks if the word is in the dictionary
                    update = misspelling[key]
                    print(update.capitalize(), end=(' '))
                else:
                    print(key.capitalize(), end=(' '))
            if capital == False:
                if key in misspelling.keys():
                    update = misspelling[key]
                    print(update, end=(' '))
                else:
                    print(key, end=(' '))
        print()
```

```
--- OUTPUT ---                               | --- OUTPUT ---                              
Sitting in the Morni sun                     | Sitting in the Morning sun                  
I will be sitting when the evening comes     | I will be sitting when the evening comes    
Watching the Ships roll in                   | Watching the Ships roll in                  
Then I watch them roll away again yeah       | Then I watch them roll away again yeah      
                                             |                                             
I am sitting on the dock of the bay          | I am sitting on the dock of the bay         
Watchin the tide roll away ooh               | Watching the tide roll away ooh             
I am just Siting on the dock of the bay      | I am just Sitting on the dock of the bay    
Wastin time                                  | Wasting time
```

Comment: For context my code is checking the spelling using a dictionary with the correct version of the word and multiple incorrect spellings of the word. So if the word is spelled wrong it should be replacing the word with the key in the dictionary (all dictionary items are lowercase). my code still works for lower case but when I tried to include the uppercase where the upper will be replaced as an upper it stopped working.

Comment: OT: please don't deconsecrate King with those g's.

Comment: isupper() will return True only if all the characters in the string are upper.  In this particular case, use index to check if the first character is upper or not.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not formatted correctly in your post so it's a little hard to read, but I think that I'm gleaning what you're trying to do. A few tips:

`isupper()` checks whether all of the characters in a string are upper-case, but usually a word is considered capitalized if just the first letter is upper-case.

`keys()` returns an iterable containing a dictionary's keys, but checking for membership in a dictionary is even easier than that: `if key in misspelling:` will check if `key` is one of the keys in the dict `misspelling`

When it comes to bools, you don't have to compare them to other bools in conditionals; instead of `if capital == True:` you should write `if capital`. And you could use else instead of then checking for a `False` condition.

Putting these ideas together:

```
    # Is the first letter of this word capitalized?
    capital = key[0].isupper()

    # Is the lowercased version of the word in the dictionary?
    in_dict = key.lower() in misspelling

    if capital and in_dict:
        # Word is capitalized and in the dictionary
        pass  # do something
    elif capital and not in_dict:
        # Word is capitalized and not in the dictionary
        pass  # do something
    elif capital and in_dict:
        # Word is not capitalized and in the dictionary
        pass  # do something
    else:
        # Word is not capitalized and not in the dictionary
        pass  # do something
```

To update a dictionary, you must access a key and replace it with someone else. `update = misspelling[key]` does not do this; it accesses the value corresponding to `key` and stores it in the variable `update`. What you probably meant to do was `misspelling[key] = key`; or something like that, it's unclear from your post what the dictionary is supposed to contain